# Terms for group of cards in a game. eg. cards in hand, on boards

Tags: single-word-requests

If **deck** is the group of all the cards in the game, how all the other groups are called?

looking for a meaningful and short terms for:

- Cards in hand
- Cards on table / board
- Cards in trash

*The player takes a card from the "cards in table" to "cards in hand", and throws away one to "cards in trash".*

more related terms can be further added

Comment: Is there a particular card game you're interested in? Poker? Bridge?

Comment: No, nothing in particular

Answer (score 2):

Terminology sometimes varies from game to game, but here are a few widely-used words:

The cards a player holds in their hand is their *hand*.

In many games the pack/deck is shuffled, the dealer deals a *hand* to each player, and puts the undealt cards face down to form a *stock*. In many games a player may take the top card off the stock. There might also be a *discard pile*, where a player may discard a card face up.

These are actions in rummy games. [Here](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/rummy.html) is a page giving rules for a basic rummy game.

Comment: The _stock_ is also known as a _stack_, I'd never come across _stock_ but the other terms I know. Could it be a regional difference? I'm British.

Comment: @BoldBen So am I. I've come across "stock" (and "stock pile") in print and web sites, but never "stack" before.

Comment: That's it, Rosie. Can't do right for doing wrong!

Comment: A _hand_ doesn't seem right. Is there another term for this?